# Convert Graphics object to Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I do have following issue with my graphics object.

**EDIT:**

I do have a picturebox_image **(imageRxTx)** which is a live stream from a camera. What I do in the paint event is to draw some lines on top of the image imageRxTx (not shown in the code below). This works so far without problem.

Now I need to check for circles in imageRxTx and therefore I have to use the method **ProcessImage()** which needs a Bitmap as parameter. Unfortunately I do not have the Bitmap image but rather the handle **(hDC)** to my imageRxTx.

**Question**: How can I get the imageRxTx from my graphics-object and "convert" it to a bitmap-image which I need to use in the method **ProcessImage(Bitmap bitmap)**? This method needs to be called continously in the paint-event in order to check the live-stream of my camera (imageRxTx).

Here my code:

```
    private void imageRxTx_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = new Settings();

        // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
        Graphics Draw = e.Graphics;
        IntPtr hDC = Draw.GetHdc(); // Get a handle to image_RxTx.           

        Draw.ReleaseHdc(hDC); // Release image_RxTx handle.


        //Here I need to send the picturebox_image 'image_RxTx' to ProcessImage as Bitmap
        AForge.Point center = ProcessImage( ?....? );    
    }


    // Check for circles in the bitmap-image
    private AForge.Point ProcessImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        //at this point I should read the picturebox_image 'image_RxTx'
        ...
```

The video image is updated here:

```
    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If Live and captured image has changed then update the window
        if (PIXCI_LIVE && LastCapturedField != pxd_capturedFieldCount(1))
        {
            LastCapturedField = pxd_capturedFieldCount(1);
            image_RxTx.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the title suggests, your main problem is a (common) misconception about what a `Graphics` object is.

*So far I can draw to my graphics object without problem*

- No! A '`Graphics`' object does **not** contain **any** graphics. It is only the **tool** used to draw graphics onto a **related** `Bitmap`. So **you don't draw onto** the `Graphics` object at all; you use it to draw onto `imageRxTx`, whatever that is, probably the surface of some `Control` or `Form`..
- This line is using an often confusing rather useless format of the `Bitmap` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/byca5y1f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

---

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image_RxTx.Width, image_RxTx.Height, Draw);
```

The last parameter is doing **next to nothing**; its only function is to copy the `Dpi` setting. In particular it does not clone or copy any content from 'Draw', which, as you know now, a `Graphics` object doesn't have anyway, nor any of its other settings. So yes, the `bmp Bitmap` is still empty after that.

If you want to draw into `bmp` you need to use a `Graphics` object that is actually bound to it:

```
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
{
   // draw now..
   // to draw an Image img onto the Bitmap use
   G.DrawImage(img, ...); 
   // with the right params for source and destination!
}
```

**None** of this should probably happen in the `Paint` event! But all the preparation code is **unclear** as to what you really want to do. You should explain just what is the source of the drawing and what is the target!

If instead you want to get the stuff you draw **onto** `image_RxTx` **into** a `Bitmap` you can use this method **somwhere outside (!)** the `Paint` event:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image_RxTx.Width, image_RxTx.Height);
image_RxTx.DrawToBitmap(bmp, image_RxTx.ClientRectangle);
```

This will **use** the `Paint` event to draw the control into a `Bitmap`. Not that the result includes the **whole** `PictureBox`: The `BackgroundImage`, the `Image` **and** the surface drawing!

**Update**: To get the **combined** content of the `PictureBox`, that is both its `Image` and what you have drawn onto the surface, you should use the code above (the last 2 lines) in the `Tick` event of a `Timer` **or** right after the line that triggers the `Paint` event. (You didn't show us how that happens.) You can't acutally put it in the `Paint` event itself, as it will use the `Paint` event and therefore would cause an infinite loop!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation..! I edited my question for clarification. What I need is the bitmap of my image_RxTx (source picturebox) as input parameter for the method ProcessImage(Bitmap). Please see my edit too - thanks.

Comment: OK, I have updated the anwser. How is the Paint event called? Do you have an Invalidate() somewhere or is it in the camera code? I hope the video is actually in the PictureBox and not just overlaid.. Can you do a screencopy?

Comment: _The Paint event is generated in InitializeComponent() at the beginning of the programm and therefore called continosly called after starting the programm._ - Hm, that makes no sense. The question is when is it __called__? (Paint is usually either called by the system, when it needs to repaint a window or by your code, eg when the things to draw have changed, eg an object has moved..

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. so you insert the two lines and possibly a third one for saving or for calling your method right after the Invalidate. Oh and since this will happen rather often I guess you should actually move the 1st line that creates the Bitmap into the InitializeComponent() and reuse the same Bitmap so you don't waste time creating it all the time nor GDI resources from not disposing of all those Bitmaps.. They all will have the same size after all.

Comment: Perfec TaW..! This was the solution at the end. Thanks a lot for your help..!

Answer (score 0):

The method `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` is probably what you're looking for.

```
var rect = myControl.DisplayRectangle;
var destBitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap))
{
    gr.CopyFromScreen(myControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), new Point(0, 0), rect.Size);
}
```

Comment: Yes this could work but I only get a white image when saving the destBitmap. Maybe it did something wrong whith the implementation. My code is: `// Create a bitmap from the Graphics object
            var rect = image_RxTx.DisplayRectangle;
            var destBitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap))
            {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(image_RxTx.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), new Point(0, 0), rect.Size);
            }
            AForge.Point center = ProcessImage(destBitmap);`

Comment: can I use a pictureBox-Image for "myControl"?

Comment: I think the problem is here: IntPtr hDC = Draw.GetHdc(); // Get a handle to image_RxTx.

I need to use this handle and convert it to a bitmap-image but how??

Comment: If you're only getting a white image then perhaps your control has not been drawn to the screen yet.  Your event handler might be firing at a time when the OS has fill in the background color but the image hasn't been painted yet.  Note that the OS does not "save" the bitmap of a control anywhere except on the screen.  If your control is obscured another window (which can be problematic if you're running a debugger that keeps popping into the foreground!) then it will have to be repainted before you can grab it.