# Get all points of Image to redraw c#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, system.drawing

Based on this post - [save a graphics object to a varbinary db column c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181621/save-a-graphics-object-to-a-varbinary-db-column-c-sharp), I created a control where I allow the user to draw on the control, and I save the drawn image to a database varbinary column. My problem is when I need to reload the signature and allow user to continue editing. I don't have all the points of the original image, so when I redraw, I only retain the user's edits.

Can somebody pls assist?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was able to set the image loaded as the image of my picture box control, I used a graphics image from that loaded image. problem solved